# Ubuntu GUI is not launching after updating from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: boot

I've got a little problem after updating from 12.04 to 12.10.
I've updated ubuntu from update manager, and then reboot it.

After the reboot I discovered that GRUB has crashed. After I repaired it, the another problem appeared, the GUI doesnt start.

In a moment it promts that `kvm:disabled by bios` four times and then text login screen appears and says:

```
Ubuntu 12.10 Marky-UB tty1

Marky-UB login: _
```

How to fix it? Help me please.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: It's totally unclear what the problem is. Have you tried anything to repair the system?

Comment: @Braiam: He has been dropped into tty1 console. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You have been dropped to a tty console instead of GUI environment. You would first need to login using tty console and then enter the GUI.

Enter your username where it says `Marky-UB login:`. Thereafter it would ask for your password. Enter your password as such. Now you have logged into Ubuntu using the console. To start the GUI environment, run the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

This would start your Unity session. From next reboot onwards, you should be automatically logged into Unity instead of tty console.